# Execute ajax function when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create a webpage that could check if a url is good or bad. The webpage is simple. There should be only a button on the webpage. Whenever the button is clicked it will check the status of the url. As a test case let's say I am checking for google.com. The problem is how do I connect the ajax function parameter with the html parameter? 
Here is what I got so far.

```
<input type="button" id="home" onclick="validate()" value="Start"/>
<br>
<p>Google Status: %s</p>
<script>
$('#home').click(function(){
  var string;
  $.ajax({
     type:'get',
     url:"https://www.google.com/",
     cache:false,
     async:asynchronous,
     dataType:json,
     success: function(result) {
         string = 'Working';
     }
     error: functionfunction(result){
         string = 'Failed';
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: *"how do I connect the ajax function parameter with the html parameter?"* Not sure what you mean by that. What exactly is an "HTML parameter"? Why do you have  `onclick="validate()"` is you are already using jQuery to bind an event handler. Please note that you cannot make an Ajax request if the server doesn't allow it. And Google probably doesn't.

Comment: Depends on the success or failure of the url, it should change the string status from either "Working" or "Failed". Sorry for the bad terms that I am using. I am totally new to front-end development. As for the onclick="validate()", so you are saying that it is totally useless? 
Thanks for the clarification sir.

Comment: How do I know if the server allows be to make Ajax request?

Comment: If you mean programmatically, then you can't.

Comment: I assume what you are asking is how to update the content of the `<p>` element? I highly recommend to read the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/

Answer (score 1):

Update text after ajax response

```
<input type="button" id="home" onclick="validate()" value="Start"/>
<br>
<p id='status'>Google Status: %s</p><!-- >change<-->
<script>
$('#home').click(function(){
var string;
 $.ajax({
     type:'get',
     url:"https://www.google.com/",
     cache:false,
     async:asynchronous,
     dataType:json,
     success: function(result) {
         $("#status").html("Google Status: Working"); // change
    }
     error: functionfunction(result){
         $("#status").html("Google Status: Failed");// change
    }
    }
);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were many errors in the ajax call itself, but the main changes I have made are to update the html of the statusText paragraph inside the success and error handlers and removed the onClick event from the button since you are adding the event handler in javascript.

```
<input type="button" id="home" value="Start"/>
<br>
<p id="statusText">Google Status:</p>
<script>
$('#home').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:"https://www.google.com/",
        cache:false,
        async:true,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(result) {
           $("#statusText").html("Google Status: Working");
        },
        error: function(result){
           $("#statusText").html("Google Status: Failed");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Well, you could at least explain the most important ones.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, You are right, updated answer to mention important changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the HTML Controls with JQUery,
And you are missing some commas, look at this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0g9zbzqr/3/

```
        $('#home').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
             url:$('#url').val(),
             type:'get',
             async:false,
             success: function(result) {
                 $("#lblResult").html($('#url').val()+': Working');
            },
             error: function(result){
                 $("#lblResult").html($('#url').val()+': Failed');
            }
            });

   });
```